# How to change the build timeout on TFS 2015 XAML build agent

Tags: xaml, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Using the on premise TFS 2015 XAML build agent.   I need to change the job timeout value.   Preferable on a build definition by build definition basis. However if I have to just changing the agent timeout value is fine as well.

It appears that the timeout is current 30 minutes.

I see no options on the Team Foundation Server Administrator Console, and no options in the build definitions.

Please note this is not a vNext build

Comment: no - this is not a vNext build agent

Comment: There should be an option under **General -> Build job timeout in minutes**

Comment: @lokusking - this is on-premise, there is no "General"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the execution time by editing the XAML build definition's "Advanced" in the Process

[image]