# Retry the failed process in TFS build without failing the build

Tags: xaml, tfs, tfsbuild, workflow-foundation

Hi I am using TFS 2013 and  writing the XAML workflow  for the TFS build to run. But in my workflow i have a CreateLabel task and sometimes due to some network issue it is getting timeout and making the TFS build to fail. I want to retry the CreateLabel process two more times and any of it get sucess i want to make the build sucesss.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, TFS does not provide any option to rerun the failed Build activities in Build Process. You may have to rerun the entire build.

---

Update

As another workaround, you could try to change the build timeout on TFS  XAML build agent. Details please follow [How to change the build timeout on TFS 2015 XAML build agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172411/how-to-change-the-build-timeout-on-tfs-2015-xaml-build-agent)

Comment: What about trying a Try Catch functionality and retrying it in the first catch

Comment: @user1654136 I don't think this could work, when an activity has run, it's not able to run it again in the build process... As a workaround, you could try to change the build  timeout on TFS  XAML build agent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172411/how-to-change-the-build-timeout-on-tfs-2015-xaml-build-agent

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT An activity can be re-executed, as long as its parent / containing activity reschedules it. I believe wrapping it in a [WhileActivity] will do the trick. That activity will reschedule its child activity(s) as long as it loops around and around.